# Javascript Сразу свернутый div. SlideToggle();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Используемую `SlideToogle();`

```
$("#test").click(function () {
  $("#forms").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Все ок рабит, но как сделать чтобы элемент по умолчанию был сверную? А то он развренут при загрузке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант #1:

```js
$("#test").click(function() {
  $("#forms").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#forms {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Кнопка</button>
<div id="forms"></div>
```

Вариант #2:

```js
$('#forms').hide();
$("#test").click(function() {
  $("#forms").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#forms {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Кнопка</button>
<div id="forms"></div>
```